# Powershell - Foreach Loop on JSON Data - How to Include Child Objects in Output IF Exists

Tags: arrays, json, powershell, foreach

I have a JSON dataset similar to the following, where in some objects we have additional data that is not present on other objects.

```
"Menu":[
   "Item 1"{
    "ID": "0001"
    "name": "Pasta",
    "price": 10.00,
    "tax": 1.00,
    "adds":[]
    }
   "Item 2"{
    "id": "0002"
    "name": "Burger",
    "price": 5.00,
    "tax": 0.50,
    "adds":[
       "id": "2001"
       "name": "cheese",
       "price": 1.00,
       "tax": 0.10
       ]
    }
   "Item 3"{
    "id": "0003"
    "name": "Cake",
    "price": 3.00,
    "tax": .30,
    "adds":[]
    }
]
```

Setting this data to a variable called $Items, I can take my for each loop and grab the details I'm looking for on each top level object..

```
    $ItemPrices = ForEach ($Item in $Items){
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = $Item.name;
        Price = $Item.price;
        ID = $Item.id;
}
```

But I would like to include data (only if it exists) from the "child object" on Item 2, the "adds" object, and the data from this sub section as well. If (adds is not null) add the same details to our array.

```
if ($null -ne $Item.adds){
   $ItemPrices += [PSCustomObject]@{ #Fails Here
        Name = $Item.adds.name;
        Price = $Item.adds.price;
        ID = $Item.adds.id;
}
```

For one, it seems that Powershell is interpreting this JSON data "adds:[]" as not being $null, I believe I can work around that. Primary issue seems to be that I get the following error for each top-level object in the list.

*Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.*

```
function Get-Menu{  
    $ItemPrices = ForEach ($Item in $Items){
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = $Item.name;
        Price = $Item.price;
        ID = $Item.id;}
    }
        
    if ($null -ne $Item.adds){
    $ItemPrices += [PSCustomObject]@{ #Fails Here
        Name = $Item.adds.name;
        Price = $Item.adds.price;
        ID = $Item.adds.id;}
    }
}
```

Expecting that, for every item in my dataset, if the "adds" section contains data, to append the selected data to our new array.

Comment: thank you. there are no hyphens in my current dataset, this was just thrown together to simplify my question and code.

replaced hyphenated ".add-ons" with ".adds"

Comment: looking at your function, by just removing `$ItemPrices +=` would solve the problem. Its not needed there as that object would be captured by `$ItemPrices = foreach...`

Comment: Your json is broken in a number of different ways - mostly missing ```,```, ```{``` and ```}``` in various places. Could you run it through a linter and patch the errors? It's hard to test locally without knowing if I'm fixing the syntax errors the right way...

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon thank you! I'm making this harder than it needs to be. Getting some goofy output, but I can work with that. This is putting me on the right path. Thanks again.

Comment: np :) but be aware, the recommendation would be to normalize your output, meaning, all your objects should have the same properties (even if their values are null). perhaps thats what you're missing in your actual code